# Insert metadata Viewport without being able to modify HTML

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, viewport

I'm gonna visualize on a WebView an external HTML page.. that I cannot modify.

Is there the possibility to insert in the HTML code "viewport" metadata before loading the request on the web view? I'd like to scale the page correctly in the UiWebview.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite clearly understood your question..but guess you are trying to append meta viewport tag without modifying the actual html...if yes, you can do it using external Javascript...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( ... );
Make DOM element like so:

MetaVa=document.createElement('meta');
Metava.name='viewport';
MetaVa.content='......';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(MetaVa);
```

Comment: That was my intention, to inject viewport after downloading html code from an external HTML page. Could you be a little more precise on the code? I'm not a Javascript guru right now..